PDF --> XLSX batch file issues
I am working on a VBA project to allow users to put in a filepath of PDFs and export them as xlsx files into a location of their choosing.
The code below works, however when it pastes the values into the Workbook, it is often super wonky/a picture instead of values.
Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this??? It's driving me insane.
I have the most updated Excel version and Adobe Acrobat.
Sub PDF_To_Excel()
    Dim setting_sh As Worksheet
    Set setting_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PDF Export")
    
    Dim pdf_path As String
    Dim excel_path As String
    
    pdf_path = setting_sh.Range("B3").Value
    excel_path = setting_sh.Range("C3").Value
    
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim fo as Folder
    Dim f as File

    Set fo = fso.GetFolder(pdf_path)

    `Dim wa As Object
     Dim doc As Object`
    `Dim wr as Object`
    
    Set wa = CreateObject("word.application")
    
    wa.Visible = True
    
    Dim nwb As Workbook
    Dim nsh As Worksheet
    
    For Each F in fo.Files
    Set doc = wa.Documents.Open(f.Path, False, Format:="PDF Files")
    Set wr = doc.Paragraphs(1).Range
    wr.WholeStory
    
    Set nwb = Workbooks.Add
    Set nsh = nwb.Sheets(1)
    wr.Copy
    
    nsh.PasteSpecial 
    nwb.SaveAs (excel_path & "\" & Replace(f.Name, ".pdf", ".xlsx))
    
    doc.Close False
    nwb Close False
    Next
    wa.Quit
    MsgBox "Done!"

    End Sub

I tried to make this accessible and not have the front-end users use powerquery (which I am open to if I can make it a macro that acheives the same thing). Any help is apprciated!

Maybe your PDF are scanned images and not actual text?

Do the same files work OK if you do this manually, or if you use powerquery?

Good question on both- let me check.

@TimWilliams These same files work just fine if done manually within the Adobe Export feature. Loading them in with Get Data via PowerQuery does seem to have issues bringing in the data at all.
